# Google play console shows warning when release application bundle

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, playstation

The problem is that I don't import any version of google play billing, neither i declare billing permission in my manifest.

Error :We've detected this app uses an unsupported version of Play billing. Please upgrade to Billing Library
version 3 or newer to publish this app.

I will check in my code no any billing dependency and no any permission for billing still i don't understand why this error coming in play console.

Comment: Quite possible you have any dependencies kind of this in your Gradle file, Or any dependency internally using that dependency. Check the dependency Tree project.

Answer (score 0):

It means that some library you're using in your project could have an inner dependency on an old version of Google Billing. You can run in your terminal either

```
gradle dependencies
```

or (if you're using the gradle wrapper)

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

When it pastes you a complete tree of dependencies, you'll be able to find the needed library.